# DB CPU parameter in AWR - Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, awr, performance-tuning

What is the significance of DB CPU paramater in Automatic Workload Repository? Say in my case it's always above 100. Does it have benchmark metric as such to say that so and so number is the right value? How does it work?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: How many CPUs do you have on this machine?

Comment: @Vérace 4 CPU. 4 Core.

Comment: I haven't worked with Oracle for a while - but IIRC, Oracle has some sort of problem summing CPU time for multi-core machines - it reports over 100%.  You could Google "oracle cpu greater than 100%" - then check out [this] post(https://community.oracle.com/thread/2276825) - search on the page for "100%".